# C# - How to test whether an instance is the default value for its type

Tags: c#

Given an instance of an unknown reference or value type, is there any way to test whether the instance contains the default value for that type? I envisage something like this ...

```
bool IsDefaultValue(object value)
{
    return value == default(value.GetType());
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because GetType returns a runtime type, but I hope that somebody can suggest a similar technique. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
static bool IsDefaultValue<T>(T input)
{
    return Object.Equals(input, default(T));
}
```

Note: you can't use `==` for equality using generic type T.

Comment: You can skip the explicit Object and just do Equals(input, default((T))

Comment: +1: Brian :) Of course, I prefer to be as explicit as possible for this kind of comparison. The OP's function is an instance method, and we don't want to call the wrong implementation of Equals.

Comment: Seems like it'd be a great extension method.